# Material ui selectFiled multi select default value was splitting into multiple values

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have implemented material -ui multiple selections, i am getting an issue with multiple selection values which means i have a default selection whose value is "hai" and when use selected another item from the dropdown whose value was "hello" and values i am getting by splitting the default value and selected value as array like ['h','a','i','hello'], its suppose to be array of two elements as ['hai','hello']. Not sure what wrong. Please find the below code snippet

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const names = [
  'hai',
  'hello',
  'how are you',
  ];


export default class SelectFieldMultiSelect extends Component {


  handleChange = (event, index, values) {
    console.log(values);
  }


  menuItems(values) {
    return names.map((name) => (
      <MenuItem
        key={name}
        checked={values && values.indexOf(name) > -1}
        value={name}
        primaryText={name}
      />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SelectField
        multiple={true}
        hintText="Select a name"
        value="hai"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={this.menuItems}
      >
      </SelectField>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've hard coded the `value` property on the `<Selectfield>` component to be "hai". Therefore, when "hai" goes through the `menuItems` function, the `menuItems` function call `map` and iterates through h, then a, then i. Remove the hardcoded value property and replace with some value on the component's state.